# What is the better way to check if a variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my application, I have the following code.

```
if (values && (values.cardNumber !== undefined)) {
```

But I have seen in some places where it looks something like this.

```
if (values && typeof (values.cardNumber !== 'undefined')) {
```

Which is the better and more secure approach to check if something is undefined??

Comment: You should keep it the way it is. `typeof` offers no advantage in practice. (Also, that would be the wrong way to use it.) Relevant answer if you’re looking for a lot of detail (ignore the accepted one): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property/22053469#22053469

Comment: Thanks RY for the info